# Can't launch an ASP.NET Website project in Rider (MacOS)

Tags: macos, jetbrains-rider

I recently downloaded Rider and I want to debug my solution, which is a ASP.NET Web App, in a MacOS environment. When I select "Run *[Solution Name]*" from the Run menu, I get this:
[image]

Keeping in mind that I haven't done anything yet to the solution; just doing a dry run. Are there any settings that need to be changed in order to get Rider to play nice? I've got version 2021.2.2.

Note: I've also got a localhost set up to do WordPress development (running on port 8888).

Comment: I'm not macos user. But describing your situation, is it related to [this](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-automatically-choose-a-free-port-in-asp-net-core/)? This article is about port 5000 is being used by a driver in macos and randomizing the application port in startup of the project is beneficial.

Comment: It turns out it is! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was trying to make it work for port 5000. Picking a new port has fixed it.
[image]